# Can't Select Text or Position Cursor When Using Multiple Redactor Editors

Tags: javascript, jquery, redactor, redactor.js

I have written the following JS to add the Redactor Text Editor plugin to any textarea fields that require it. I'm using version 10.1.1

```
var addRedactor = {
    init: function(element) {
        $.each(element, function(key, value) {
            $(value).find('.redactor').redactor({
                buttonSource: true,
                plugins: ['table', 'video'],
                imageUpload: '/upload-redactor-image',
                linkEmail: true,
                linkAnchor: true,
                convertVideoLinks: true,
                minHeight: 180,
                autoresize: false
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Basically, I pass the parent element of the textarea I want to add Redactor to, to the init function of 'addRedactor' and then iterate over each parent element applying the Redactor plugin to any input that has a class of 'redactor'.

This works fine until you have multiple Redactor editors on one page. In this scenario, you are unable to select the text or position the cursor.

I'm not receiving any JS errors in the console.

Comment: Same problem here. Any chance you found a solution?

Comment: I did find a solution and it wasn't a problem with Redactor. I had JS code for something else I was building using jQuery UI that stopped selection on a specific element. This of course affected Redactor. Once I removed it it was all OK.

Comment: :) In the end, same here...   I puzzled with redactor IDs for hours until I realised it was inside a .`sortable` with `.disableSelection()` added.  I appreciate you  getting back on this.

Comment: That was exactly my problem, with .disableSelection()